# Convert a character string with an index to an object reference

Tags: r, object, reference, formula

I am parsing the left-hand side of an R formula. In my specific case, this can be a variable or object with an index (something like `myvariable[[3]]`). I would like to access the third sub-object of this object and store it in another object. The following example starts at the point where I have the string of the indexed object, but I need the reference.

```
mychars <- c("a", "b", "c")
mystring <- "mychars[2]"
get(mystring)                # does not work
eval(as.name(mystring))      # does not work either
```

I could of course parse the number using regular expressions and use `as.numeric` to convert it to a real index. But in some cases, there may be named indices, like `mystring["second"]`. So how can I extract the sub-object?

Comment: Why are you doing this? More specifically what gain is there to storing executable code inside character-typed objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `parse` and then `eval` this expression.

```
mychars <- c("a", "b", "c")
mystring <- "mychars[2]"
eval(parse(text = mystring))
[1] "b"
```

It works for named indices too

```
names(mychars) <- c("first", "second", "third")
eval(parse(text = 'mychars["second"]'))
second 
   "b"
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was fiddling around with `eval(parse(object))` already, but I was not including the `text =` part...

Comment: @SpammerSlammer True, you were pretty close :-)

Comment: `fortunes::fortune("parse()")`